# How to make a custom mapping from a csv column to some custom code?

Tags: c#, csv, class, mapping, csvhelper

I have **generated entities** classes (like MyClass), and I need to read a csv file, and then return a List of MyClass.
On all entities, we have a **readonly** property **CreateOn**.
To set the CreatedOn, we need to do this custom code : Attributes["overriddencreatedon"] = DateTime.Now;

Is it possible with CsvHelper to do something like this ? :

```
public class MyClass // in real life, inherits from  Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get;} // Readonly because generated class...
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }
}

private class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        Map(f => f.Id).Name("Id");
        // Cannot do this : Map(f => f.CreatedOn).Name("CreatedOn");
        // Because CreatedOn is readonly
        // The goal is to store the value in the dictionary Attributes, not in the property CreatedOn because it is readonly
        // Instead, we need to do something like this:
        Map().XXX((row, x) => x.Attributes["overriddencreatedon"] = row.Row.GetField<DateTime>("CreatedOn"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a constructor that has a `createdOn` argument?  How is it set normally?  Can the class `MyClass` be modified in any way?

Comment: @dbc I think the confusion is that [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity?view=dataverse-sdk-latest) doesn't have a `CreatedOn` property.  I believe `CreatedOn` would be included in the `Attributes`, but you can't set `CreatedOn` directly, you have to use `overriddencreatedon` to set `CreatedOn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for `Dictionary<string, object> Attributes`.

```cs
Map(f => f.Attributes).Convert(args =>
{
    return new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "overriddencreatedon", args.Row.GetField<DateTime>("CreatedOn") }
    };
});
```

If `MyClass` inherits from `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity` then it should be `AttributeCollection Attributes`.

```cs
Map(f => f.Attributes).Convert(args =>
{
    return new AttributeCollection {
        { "overriddencreatedon", args.Row.GetField<DateTime>("CreatedOn") }
    };
});
```

Comment: This solution works but this must be the first call to the Map function. For example, my line of code   Map(f => f.Id).Name("Id"); must be after your code.

Comment: That's strange.  I wouldn't think the order of the function calls would matter.  I had tried it with `MyClass` inheriting from `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity` and it seemed to work just fine that way.